# Installed new blower with problems

Tags: blower

Had a problem a few years ago with my blower motor. Tech who came to my home said he would save me money as it only needed to be oiled.
Worked fine for 5 years after that. 
Recently I noticed that when the thermostat called for cooling sometimes the fan would not come on yet the AC outside would still be running and quickly would ice over.
Bought a new Dayton blower motor today...this one was recommended by a tech at Graingers.
New motor has a capacitor...old one did not.
Anyway..problem is when the thermostat calls for cooling the compressor runs...sometimes the motor makes 2 sounds like it’s trying to start over and over until I stop it...or doesn’t come on at all.
Any ideas from the experts as to what might be wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Oiled? Then it's the bearings on the squirrel cage. Take the belt off and spin it. Bet you it doesn't like to spin. Even if there's no belt, check that it spins freely (did you put it on the shaft too tight and now one side has no clearance?).

Comment: You may have jumped too soon to buy a motor. Sounds like the trouble might be the fan itself (as @Mazura mentioned) or electrical control. Does the new motor start correctly when it's not hooked up to the fan? If it does, I'd say it's the fan bearings.